# Finding the last "}" of a subroutine

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, module, subroutine

Supposed I have a file with Perl-code: does somebody know, if there is a module which could find the closing "}" of a certain subroutine in that file. 
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;

routine_one( '{°^°}' );

routine_two();

sub routine_one {
    my $arg = shift;
    if ( $arg =~ /}\z/ ) {
    say "Hello my }";
    }
}

sub routine_two {
    say '...' for 0 .. 10
}
```

The module should be able to remove the whole routine_one or it should can tell me the line-number of the closing "}" from that routine.

Comment: Perl code is not regular, so what makes you think that you can parse it with a *regular* expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PPI/) if you are going to be parsing Perl code.

Comment: @cjm I wasn't aware you could make links like that.  Thanks.

Comment: Look for the "permalink" near the upper right corner of the page.  It is fairly easy to overlook.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use PPI;

my $file = 'Example.pm';

my $doc = PPI::Document->new( $file );
$doc->prune( 'PPI::Token::Pod' );
$doc->prune( 'PPI::Token::Comment' );
my $subs = $doc->find( sub { $_[1]->isa('PPI::Statement::Sub') and $_[1]->name eq 'layout' } );
die if @$subs != 1;

my $new = PPI::Document->new( \qq(sub layout {\n    say "my new layout_code";\n}) );
my $subs_new = $new->find( sub { $_[1]->isa('PPI::Statement::Sub') and $_[1]->name eq 'layout' } );


$subs->[0]->block->insert_before( $subs_new->[0]->block ) or die $!;
$subs->[0]->block->remove or die $!;


# $subs->[0]->replace( $subs_new->[0] );
# The ->replace method has not yet been implemented at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.2/PPI/Element.pm line 743.

$doc->save( $file ) or die $!;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work in case your subroutines don't contain any blank lines, like the one in your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

$^I = ".bkp";  # to create a backup file

{
   local $/ = ""; # one paragraph constitutes one record
   while (<>) {
      unless (/^sub routine_one \{.+\}\s+$/s) {  # 's' => '.' will also match "\n"
         print;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is only an example, the real routine looks different.